# Fast moving object passing through other objects

Tags: collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I am pretty new to Unity and am making a small example. Actually I have a cube which moves with my arrow keys. Now I have walls on the road, and I want my object to hit the wall but it pass through the wall.

I also have used this code, but no result:

http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=DontGoThroughThings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to track the last position of your object(s), and then when they move, cast a ray from the current position to the last position. Check the ray for collisions and if there are any, you've gone though an object.

If you have gone though another object, set the you current object to the position reported by the collision. The next frame will trigger the collision events.

The link you provided does in fact do this.

Comment: Your answer is correct but in my case i do not know why it was not working. so then i have applied force on the object rather then changing its positions.

Comment: If collisions were working at slower movement speed but not larger ones, there may be issue with the code. If collisions were not working at slower speeds, you may have missed adding a rigidbody to your object. If you want to move everything via code rather than via forces, just set the rigidbody to `Is Kinematic` and forces wont effect it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were doing something like:

```
transform.velocity.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

That won't work with collisions because you're not actually colliding with anything, you're just teleporting by a fixed amount each frame. This causes you to actually teleport INSIDE of an object.